# Why can't I open a specific rar file in a specific computer, but it opens on other computer?

Tags: file-recovery, rar

It's pretty much the topic.
I have a 8 GB rar file that opens in my windows 8.1 pc, but it doesn't open in my old laptop with windows 7. I tried 7zip and i have the same result.

It always says it's unknown archive or damaged, but it opens perfectly on my newest computer.

Any hint on why would this happen?

Edit: I forgot to mention I have another old laptop with windows 7, in which the same problem would occur.

Comment: Is the old Win7 OS the 32-bit version?

Comment: No it's 64bit..

Comment: What kind of media is the file on? Did you copy it or is it an external media that you move from one to the other?

Comment: I tried on a external USB HDD. Then tried copying into the main hard drive, then on a usb pen, with the file copied right from the main computer (where the file opens). It doesn't open in any media. It only opens in the main computer. The old laptop has only 4GB ram, i suspected it could be that but needed confirmation

Comment: Yeah, that might be it. Try zipping it up with the feature that will split the archive in to chunks. Split it in to 2GB parts: http://www.ncl.ac.uk/itservice/file-drop-off/splittingandrecombiningfiles/

Comment: Yes, that did the trick. If I extract them and re-compress in several small files it opens right away. Thank you.

Comment: Silly question, but is your file system NTFS or FAT32?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer was that @ng80092b had less available RAM than the size of the archive he was trying to open. The solution to this problem was re-creating the archive split in to smaller chunks. I recommend using 2GB chunks for compatibility with systems that only have 4GB of total RAM.

**Instructions for 7-Zip:**
Splitting up files

1. Start the 7-Zip software

[image]

Navigate to the location of the file you wish to split

2. Select the file and select 'Add' from the toolbar (green + icon)

[image]

In the resulting dialogue box,

```
change 'archive type' to ZIP
'Split to volumes, bytes' - 2048M
```

[image]

7-Zip will save slices of the original file into the same folder, with a .zip suffix followed by a sequence number (e.g. 'test.zip.001, test.zip.002, ...)

Source:
http://www.ncl.ac.uk/itservice/file-drop-off/splittingandrecombiningfiles/

Answer (score 2):

Try running memory diagnostics on the computer in question. I had this exact same issue on win 7 x64 with WinRAR. It wound up being a bad ddr3 memory module.

Comment: Thank you Tim. I've added an edition, unless I have 2 computers with bad memory modules (which would be pretty rare) that isn't the issue. Also, all the other rar files open, in all of the computers.

Comment: What size are the other rar files compared to this one? I'm assuming you have done the basics, tried to repair the archive etc.